# Поиск связей на основе множественных данных

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть вот такая задачка.
 Имеем определенные данные, на основе этих данных необходимо найти связь по типу Alpha - Gamma. 
Условия следующие:

```
alpha['code'] != beta['code'] and list(set(alpha['cls']) & set(beta['cls']))
```

(и так со всеми "узлами" от Alpha до Theta); 
если связь Alpha - Gamma разрешена, то Gamma - Alpha уже запрещена (связь возможна только в одностороннем порядке); 
количество связей для каждого "узла" не должно превышать значений `linkMax` и не должно быть ниже значений `linkMin`.
Ума не приложу как оформит это, кроме как в примере кода.
 Есть какие-то более удобные варианты? 
Выручайте. Заранее спасибо.

```
comp_list = ['Альфа', 'Бета', 'Гамма', 'Дельта', 'Эпсилон', 'Дзета', 'Эта','Тета']
    linkMin = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
    linkMax = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
    i_v_list = [5000000, 1000000, 8000000, 15000000, 1900000, 49420, 7840000, 10200000]
    f_v_list = [2500, 7800000, 15000000, 4700, 9378000, 6940000, 9863420, 800]
    i_t_list = [2082292, 41717791, 57455285, 7886851, 39717241, 31947667, 35374341, 39077395]
    o_t_list = [7079792, 34917791, 50455285, 22882151, 32239241, 25057087, 33350921, 49276595]
    cod_list = [5445, 4205, 5405, 5405, 2464, 9204, 9204, 2464]

alpha_cls = [432100, 192000, 421100, 932990]
beta_cls = [521000, 466900, 842509, 711210]
gamma_cls = [521000, 421100, 842509, 711210]
delta_cls = [0, 412000, 711210, 932990]
epsilon_cls = [467100, 421100, 521000, 711210]
zeta_cls = [192000, 466900, 711210]
eta_cls = [842509, 421100, 521000, 932990]
theta_cls = [421100, 466900, 711210, 932990]

alpha = {'name': comp_list[0], 'code': cod_list[0], 'cls': alpha_cls}
beta = {'name': comp_list[1], 'code': cod_list[1], 'cls': beta_cls}
gamma = {'name': comp_list[2], 'code': cod_list[2], 'cls': gamma_cls}
delta = {'name': comp_list[3], 'code': cod_list[3], 'cls': delta_cls}
epsilon = {'name': comp_list[4], 'code': cod_list[4], 'cls': epsilon_cls}
zeta = {'name': comp_list[5], 'code': cod_list[5], 'cls': zeta_cls}
eta = {'name': comp_list[6], 'code': cod_list[6], 'cls': eta_cls}
theta = {'name': comp_list[7], 'code': cod_list[7], 'cls': theta_cls}

nodes = (alpha, beta, gamma, delta, epsilon, zeta, eta, theta)

if alpha['code'] != beta['code'] and list(set(alpha['cls']) & set(beta['cls'])):
    print('Link possible')
else:
    print('Link impossible', alpha['name'], '-', beta['name'])

if alpha['code'] != gamma['code'] and list(set(alpha['cls']) & set(gamma['cls'])):
    print('Link possible', alpha['name'], '-', gamma['name'])
else:
    print('Link impossible', alpha['name'], gamma['name'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так должно сработать. Все связи хранятся в словаре `links`:

```
comp_list = ['Альфа', 'Бета', 'Гамма', 'Дельта', 'Эпсилон', 'Дзета', 'Эта','Тета']
linkMin = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
linkMax = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
i_v_list = [5000000, 1000000, 8000000, 15000000, 1900000, 49420, 7840000, 10200000]
f_v_list = [2500, 7800000, 15000000, 4700, 9378000, 6940000, 9863420, 800]
i_t_list = [2082292, 41717791, 57455285, 7886851, 39717241, 31947667, 35374341, 39077395]
o_t_list = [7079792, 34917791, 50455285, 22882151, 32239241, 25057087, 33350921, 49276595]
cod_list = [5445, 4205, 5405, 5405, 2464, 9204, 9204, 2464]

alpha_cls = [432100, 192000, 421100, 932990]
beta_cls = [521000, 466900, 842509, 711210]
gamma_cls = [521000, 421100, 842509, 711210]
delta_cls = [0, 412000, 711210, 932990]
epsilon_cls = [467100, 421100, 521000, 711210]
zeta_cls = [192000, 466900, 711210]
eta_cls = [842509, 421100, 521000, 932990]
theta_cls = [421100, 466900, 711210, 932990]

alpha = {'name': comp_list[0], 'code': cod_list[0], 'cls': alpha_cls}
beta = {'name': comp_list[1], 'code': cod_list[1], 'cls': beta_cls}
gamma = {'name': comp_list[2], 'code': cod_list[2], 'cls': gamma_cls}
delta = {'name': comp_list[3], 'code': cod_list[3], 'cls': delta_cls}
epsilon = {'name': comp_list[4], 'code': cod_list[4], 'cls': epsilon_cls}
zeta = {'name': comp_list[5], 'code': cod_list[5], 'cls': zeta_cls}
eta = {'name': comp_list[6], 'code': cod_list[6], 'cls': eta_cls}
theta = {'name': comp_list[7], 'code': cod_list[7], 'cls': theta_cls}

nodes = (alpha, beta, gamma, delta, epsilon, zeta, eta, theta)
links={key['name']: [] for key in nodes}
node_number=0

for start in nodes: # перебираем начальные ноды
    for end in nodes: #  перебираем конечные ноды
        # условия отбора
        cond1 = start['code'] != end['code']
        cond2 = list(set(start['cls']) & set(end['cls']))
        cond3 = start['name'] not in links[end['name']]
        cond4 = len(links[start['name']]) < linkMax[node_number]

        if  cond1 and cond2 and cond3 and cond4:
            print('Link possible', start['name'], '-', end['name']
                  )
            links[start['name']].append(end['name'])
        else:
            print('Link impossible', start['name'], '-', end['name'])
    node_number+=1
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это работает!!!

Comment: @RomanGagarin отметьте ответ галочкой пожалуйста